# ioctl call always returns -1,but works anyways

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a simple device driver for sending and receiving a structure between user application and the driver using ioctl.
Here is my unlocked ioctl function -

```
long ioctl_func(struct file *filep,unsigned int cmd,unsigned long arg)
{
int ret = 0;

struct ioctl_struct *my_struct = kmalloc(sizeof(struct ioctl_struct),GFP_KERNEL);
struct ioctl_struct *my_struct1 = kmalloc(sizeof(struct ioctl_struct),GFP_KERNEL);  
switch(cmd)
{
    case CMD_WRITE_STRUCT:
            printk("Inside CMD_WRITE_STRUCT\n");
            ret = copy_from_user(my_struct,(struct ioctl_struct *)arg,sizeof(struct ioctl_struct));
            if(ret > 0)
            {
                printk("Error copy_from_user\n");
                return -1;
            }
            printk("Structure received from user app:\nid = %d\nname = %s\ndata = %ld\n",my_struct->id,my_struct->name,my_struct->data);    
            return 0;
    case CMD_READ_STRUCT:   
            printk("Inside CMD_READ_STRUCT\n");
            my_struct1->id = 99;
            strcpy(my_struct1->name,"Hello User!");
            my_struct1->data = 65535;
            ret = copy_to_user((char *)arg,my_struct1,sizeof(struct ioctl_struct));
            if(ret)
            {
                printk("Error copy_to_user\n");
            }   return -1;

            printk("Sent structure to user\n");
            return 0;       


    default: printk("Invalid ioctl cmd\n");
         break;
}
return 0;

}
```

I am being able to pass a structure from user application to driver successfully using consecutive CMD_WRITE_STRUCT commands.
However,once i do a CMD_READ_STRUCT, ioctl call on the user application returns -1 ,with error "operation not permitted",but structure is successfully copied to user.
After an CMD_READ,CMD_WRITE doesnt work anymore as ioctl shows error "invalid file descriptor".
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `ioctl_struct` struct? Also `copy_to_user` returns `unsigned long`.  What kernel version? Do you free anywhere `my_struct` and `my_struct1`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Here is the ioctl_struct -                                                                                  `struct ioctl_struct
{
 int id;
 char name[20];
 unsigned long data;
};`

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry for the formatting.i am new here. Kernel version is 4.9.35-v7+ , running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.i am freeing `my_struct` and `my_struct1` only in the `close` function of my driver.

Comment: What is shown by `dmesg` when you perform ioctl operations? You have `printk` in the every code branch, it looks unreasonable that you don't check its output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code has a simple issue here which explains this: "However,once i do a CMD_READ_STRUCT, ioctl call on the user application returns -1 ,with error "operation not permitted",but structure is successfully copied to user. "

```
if(ret)
{
    printk("Error copy_to_user\n");
}   return -1;
```

it should be like

```
if(ret)
{
    printk("Error copy_to_user\n");
    return -1;
}
```

For the other issue I think maybe you have put some error checking in your application which would close the file in case of -1 return. Just a wild guess.